# Getting tons of diagnostic comments in DOM in my Angular 12+ project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

In my Angular project I have an case where I should show an navigation bar by condition and for that I'm using next code.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'padding': standardItems && standardItems.length > 0 ? '0' : '0 16px'}"
     class="header-panel-section__fm">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of constData">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="item.Type">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="PanelTypes.LOGOIMAGE">
        <img
          [routerLink]="'/' + configService.lang + item?.Href"
          class='header-logo__fm'
          [ngStyle]="{'width' : logoWidth ? logoWidth : '96px'}"
          [src]="'/assets/images/' + (configService.lightLogoPath$ | async) + item.Icon"
          alt="{{configService?.hostName}}"
          width="100%"
          height="100%">
      </div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="PanelTypes.TIME" class="timezone__fm color-timezone__fm">
        {{todayDate | date : "H:mm:ss"}} {{todayDate | date: 'zzz' }}
      </div>

************ many other cases *******
          </div>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

after running project in inspect elements it shows MANY diagnostic comments like this
[image]

I researche on the internet found it says, should be added enableProdMode(); in main.ts.

but it removed only content and shows in inspect elements the following

[image]

How can I rid of these comments from the browser's inspect elements?

Comment: But that's how Angular manages it's DOM. Does it only bothers you or you actually face any issues?

Comment: It's can be visible even in production mode and making some SEO issues

Comment: You mean like this: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5536/do-html-comments-affect-seo